# How to stop renewing a letsencrypt/certbot certificate?

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

There are lots of tutorials online of how to create and renew a certificate with letsencrypt, but I want to remove and stop renewing a certificate that I created (it was only created for testing purposes). How do I stop renewing one certificate originally obtained with the `letsencrypt` command (while still continuing to renew other certificates)?

I don't see a single instance of anyone asking this question anywhere else, nor a command in `man letsencrypt` that seems to do it.

Currently I am renewing certificates with the following cron job:

```
30 2 * * 1 /usr/bin/letsencrypt renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
35 2 * * 1 /bin/systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: You might need to give more details-- usually that's not automagical. I've a  cronjob that handles this monthly. I just comment that out if I want to disable it (`crontab -e`).

Comment: @DavidBetz Updated with more details. It's not as simple as disabling the cron job, because I have other certificates on this server that I still want to renew.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

With `certbot`, you can simply use:

```
certbot delete --cert-name mywebsite.com
```

This removes the certificate and all relevant files from your letsencrypt config directory.

Comment: Yes, the selected answer -- while it was right I'm sure, is outdated. This answer is the correct answer and it'd be great if that could be updated.

Comment: If you use `certbot delete` you'll get an interactive menu

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got a confirmation prompt, and then a message "No certificate was found with name". Yet, subsequent attempt to renew everything failed again citing this particular domain as the culprit (it is no longer in DNS).

Answer (score 33):

The OP wants to delete the certificate in addition to stopping renewal, and that was covered by the other answers. However if you want to keep the certificate but discontinue future renewals (for example if you have switched to a different server, but are waiting for all the DNS changes to propagate), you can go into `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal` and rename `example.com.conf` to `example.com.conf.disabled` (or any other non-`.conf` name, or even delete it altogether:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf.disabled
```

You can verify it was disabled by running the following command, as noted in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669130/421049).

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

Lastly some have [suggested elsewhere](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-disable-auto-renew-for-a-domain/57159/4) that one can simple put `autorenew = False` at the top of the `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf` file, but that doesn't seem to work. (I would have replied to that post to give my feedback, but their forum cuts off comments after 30 days.)

After review I realize that much of this information is included in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669130/421049), but I wanted to clarify the steps needed for the separate use case of disabling renewal without deleting or disabling the certificate itself.

Comment: The option autorenew = False works perfectly for me. I put the option under the [renewalparams] section of the configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mycert.conf and the renew was simply skipped.

Comment: Renaming the file with the .disabled extension worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't seem like there is a command to formally "cancel" renewals at this time. However, I found a suggestion from [this thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/correct-way-to-completely-remove-issued-certificate-s-for-a-domain/7409) that seems to work.

I tried running the following command,

```
sudo find /etc/letsencrypt/ -name '*outdated.example.com*'
```

and only found one file in each the `live/`, `archive/` and `renewal/` directory.

I also tried running,

```
sudo grep -r /etc/letsencrypt/ -e 'outdated.example.com'
```

and only found references to the outdated domain in one file in the `renewal/` directory (which was `renewal/outdated.example.com.conf`).

I ran `letsencrypt renew` and it listed `outdated.example.com` in the output.

I then created a directory `_renewal_disabled` and moved `renewal/outdated.example.com.conf` to that directory.

I ran `letsencrypt renew` again, and it no longer listed `outdated.example.com` in the output.

From this I can assume that I've "disabled" renewal of the certificate.

Comment: Today (2017) is possible to use only `certbot renew`? How to do it?

Answer (score 7):

### updated

Please see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47372583/1426788

A newer version of [certbot supports deleting certs via the CLI](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-command-line-options)

### old answer

To remove a domain from your certbot renewals, you can remove or move (safer) the bad domain cert files and run `certbot renew --dry-run` to ensure that you have removed the outdated / invalid configuration.

```
rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/live/${BAD_DOMAIN}/
rm -f /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/${BAD_DOMAIN}.conf
certbot renew --dry-run
```

If that works, you can continue your renewals without `--dry-run` for future updates.

```
certbot renew
```

If you're running with something like `nginx` or some other server, don't forget to edit your configs so they are no longer pointing to invalid or removed certs.

Finally, restart or reload your server configs and you're done!

Answer (score 4):

The following provides an interactive menu:

```
certbot delete
```

You can also delete a certificate non-interactively using `certbot delete --cert-name example.com`, but this appears to go through the normal authorisation process, and will fail if it can't authorise your domain.  The interactive command above deletes everything without trying to authorise.

Comment: I know it's a newer feature, but this should be the accepted answer. Had so much trouble trying to do it with `--cert-name` , this work ez pz

Answer (score 1):

In a Debian system using the Certbot snap. Edit `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mydomain.com.conf` adding `autorenew = False` under `[renewalparams]`:

```
version = 2.7.4
...
# Options used in the renewal process                                                                                                                                                                       
[renewalparams]
...
autorenew = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do/did:

1. I ran

```
certbot renew
```

and noted which domains were not renewing or had problems

2. I created a

```
/etc/certbot/disabled
```

directory to hold disabled (but not deleted) domains

3. On a case-by-case basis, I moved all undesired ***.conf** files from **/etc/certbot/renewal** into **/etc/certbot/disabled**

```
#cd /etc/certbot/renewal
#mv <disabled_domain> ../disabled
```

4. I then resolved all special cases:

4A)  Default "catchall" server website

```
#certbot --apache -d <server.catchall.url>
```

4B)  Mail Server

i) Stop httpd

```
#service httpd stop
```

ii)  Issue certbot command to generate the certificate

```
#certbot certonly --standalone -d <mail.server.domain>
```

iii) Start httpd

```
#service httpd start
```

iv) Check httpd

```
#service httpd status
```

5. I added a command to my cron job to check for certificate expiry every week, on Sunday

```
# GL  2019-12-09  Renew Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate
#                 Execute every Sunday at noon
00 12 * * Sun     /bin/python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && /bin/certbot renew >> /var/log/certbot.log 2>&1
```

This resolved my issues.